# Woocommerce choose product option for Custom Attribute for product variable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a variable product in woocommerce and I am creating an attribute called Framing. The following are being used as variation: No Framing|StandardPlaq|AlumaPlaq|Slate|Traditional Framing

I set up the prices for each variable etc and the product is live. However, the error I am receiving is that "please choose product option"

http://www.courthousesofamerica.com/shop/courthouses-america-giclee-print/lawyer-always-taking-notes-1902/

Why is this so? How do I resolve this error?

Is it a problem with the theme? or woocommerce? or any plugin?

Comment: I'd advise you to test against a default theme, and test disable other plugins. Then you can narrow the problem down.

Comment: Hi. i have just changed to the default theme. the prices are then being correctly updated. it means that on the gift present premium theme that there is the problem.. however, don't know how to resolve the error..